# Ethernaut Challenge #26 DoubleEntryPoint

Tags: solidity

I'm following the tutorial https://dev.to/erhant/ethernaut-26-double-entry-point-1nfp. I don't understand this snippet:

```
// find the CryptoVault address from DoubleEntryPoint
const cryptoVaultAddress = await contract.cryptoVault()

// access "IERC20 public underlying;" variable
await web3.eth.getStorageAt(cryptoVaultAddress, 1)
// 0x00000000000000000000000025047168b9c737a03a111ec039438403e73b7507
```

- Why do we need to access "IERC20 public underlying;" variable?
- Why do we need to set 1 for `await web3.eth.getStorageAt(cryptoVaultAddress, 1)`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a way to get the address of the underlying token. Since the main contract in the challenge is *DoubleEntryPoint*, it will get saved under the contract variable.

This means in order to access variables of the vault contract, you would need to instantiate a new contract instance *CryptoVault* and call CryptoVault.underlying. But using getStorageAt() is the easier option because it returns the value saved in the given storage slot of the given contract. The storage would look like this (since it starts with 0):

0. sweptTokensRecipient
1. underlying

So calling `await web3.eth.getStorageAt(cryptoVaultAddress, 1)` will give you the value of underlying.

It's just used to check the actual underlying token.

Comment: CryptoVault is one contract, and DoubleEntryPoint is another contract. I don't get how referencing a storage slot #1 (underlying) on CryptoVault has anything to do with the cryptoVault variable on DoubleEntryPoint, needless to say how it can retrieve the value of the underlying contract address (cryptoVaultAddress).

Comment: If you are referencing this line: `const cryptoVaultAddress = await contract.cryptoVault()`, it is only used to retrieve the actual cryptoVaultAddress that is connected to the DoubleEntryPoint.

Comment: How is the actual cryptoVaultAddress connected to the DoubleEntryPoint?

Comment: Why is the slot for "underlying" variable chosen to be accessed?

Comment: It's set as address public cryptoVault in the first slot of DoubleEntryPoint. The underlying is only accessed to check what the underlying token actually is. If it weren't the DoubleEntryPoint, then this hack would not be possible.